# Acessing structure declared from another file->Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective C.

```
remote.h

struct RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG
{
    int  uDeviceID;
    int  uProtocolVersion;
    int  uReserved[5];
};

    @interface remote : NSObject {
   }
    @end




   data_derived.h

    #import "remote.h"

    @interface data_derived : data {

    @public
     RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG st;

}

@end
```

> Error:Expected
>   specifier-qualifier-list before
>   'RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG'

Here the structure declaration is made outside but i could not able to assign a variable

for this structure in another class that is declared in another file.I'm getting an

error.What has to be done to clear up this error.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
struct RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG st;
```

instead of

```
RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG st;
```

structure implementation in objective C is similiar to C structures..we need struct keyword when declaring structure variables..Else you can use typedef

```
typedef struct {
    int data1;
    char data2;
} RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG;
```

and later..

```
RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG st;
```